# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `show`. How do I pass a boolean for a custom boolean attribute?

Tags: reactjs

I have received the following warning:

> Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `show`.
>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead:
>   show="false" or show={value.toString()}.
>
> If you used to conditionally omit it with show={condition && value},
>   pass show={condition ? value : undefined} instead

I'm tried to figure out how to pass a string to the DOM in the Modal Window react component. I'm passing the string through the component. Here is my code below:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    
    
    
    const Modal = ({ show, children }) => {
      const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
    
      return (
        <div className={showHideClassName}>
          <section className='modal-main'>
          {children}
          </section>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    class App extends React.Component {
        state = { show: false }
    
        showSignup = () => {
            this.setState({ show: true });
        }
    
        showLogin = () => {
            this.setState({ show: true });
        }
    
        hideModal = () => {
            this.setState({ show: false });
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <Modal show={this.state.show} handleclose={this.hideModal} >
                    <div className="blkOverlay">
                        {/* This is Login Form to log in to your profile */ }
                        <div className="formContent modal-main">
                            <button className="closebtn" onClick={this.hideModal}>Close </button>
                            <h2>Welcome Back <span>Brandon!</span></h2>
                            <form show={this.state.show} handleclose={this.hideModal}>
                               
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                                <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
                                <div className="passContent">
                                    <div className="checkingPass">
                                        <input className="inline" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Remember Password"/>
                                        <span className="inline">Remember Password</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <p className="passFont">Forgot Password</p>
                                </div>
                                
                                <input className="formmbtn" type="button" name="button" value="Login"/>
                                <div className="social-media-button">
                                    <input className="clearbtn" type="button" name="button" value="Sign in with Facebook"/>
                                    <div class="divider"/>
                                    <input className="clearbtn" type="button" name="button" value="Sign in with Facebook"/>
                                </div>
    
                                <p className="passFont">Don't have an account? <span>Sign up</span></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
    
                        {/* This is Sign up to create a account */}
                    </div>
                </Modal>
              </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: On which line you are seeing this error

Answer (score 1):

Neither `show` nor `handleclose` are valid DOM properties.

```
<form show={this.state.show} handleclose={this.hideModal}>
```

I am not sure the exact use case of having the show attribute in thie HTML Form element, but I suppose the closest you can get when it comes to attaching custom properties to HTML elements would be through the use of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In addition, you will need to convert the boolean value to a string.

```
<form data-show={this.state.show.toString()}>
```

Comment: The show was going to be used to show the modal window where you click on the button to view the form. I got to from tutorial I was read so I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Ahh.. But `show` and `handleclose` are actually props of the `Modal ` component. You have already added them there.

Comment: This tutorial trying to figure to work and show and hide the modal window but just not good to solve a coding problem --> https://alligator.io/react/modal-component/